# Error with RLQ and Fourth Corner Analysis: "tabR" must contain only numeric values or factors" even though it seems that they already are

Tags: dataframe, numeric

I'm currently trying to run and RLQ analysis which conducts a double inertia analysis on two arrays R and Q, which represent ecological environmental variables and species traits respectively, which are linked via a contingency table representing abundance data (L) of those weed species found within each 'environment', in this case sample sites.

I am doing this following the tutorial from Stéphane Dray titled "A tutorial to perform fourth-corner and RLQ analyses in R (2013). The process first involves running separate analyses on each data frame (Correspondence Analysis for the species abundance table, and Hill-Smith Analysis for the environmental and traits tables as they contain both quantitative and numerical values. This step has worked out fine, but the following one (the fourth-corner) utilises these data frames (not the analyses performed on them) once more. I have used the code from the tutorial as am completely new to this, which reads:

```
FourthCorner <- fourthcorner(Environmental, Species, Traits, modeltype = 6, p.adjust.method.G = "none", p.adjust.method.D = "none", nrepet = nrepret).
```

When doing so however, I get the following error:

```
Error in fourthcorner(tabR, tabL, tabQ, modeltype = 2, nrepet = nrepet,  : 
      'tabR' must contain only numeric values or factors (see the 'Treatment' variable in    'tabR').
```

[The first 10 samples in my environmental data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96Sto.png)
Apologies for not putting the data directly but it is my first time trying  this.

I first tried setting my categorical variables in my R and Q data frames as factors, while leaving the remaining quantitative variables as numerical:

```
Environmental$Field <- as.factor(Environmental$Field)
    Environmental$Treatment <- as.factor(Environmental$Treatment)
```

I then tried setting all my categorical variables to numerical, which also did not work:

```
Environmental$Field <- as.numeric(Environmental$Field)
    Environmental$Treatment <- as.numeric(Environmental$Treatment)
```

And again for all my environmental variables:

```
Environmental$Field <- as.numeric(as.character(Environmental$Field))
    Environmental$Treatment <- as.numeric(as.character(Environmental$Treatment))
    Environmental$Moisture_content_perc <- as.numeric(Environmental$Moisture_content_perc)
    Environmental$Soil_organic_matter_gkg <- as.numeric(Environmental$Soil_organic_matter_gkg)
    Environmental$N_NO3_gkg <- as.numeric(Environmental$N_NO3_gkg)
    Environmental$N_NH4_gkg <- as.numeric(Environmental$N_NH4_gkg)
    Environmental$P_PO4_gkg <- as.numeric(Environmental$P_PO4_gkg)
    Environmental$K_gkg <- as.numeric(Environmental$K_gkg)
```

I tried removing one environmental variable from the R table at a time but the error simply shifted to the following variable (even ones that seemed clearly numerical).

When running the `as.numeric(variable)`  for each, the result is `TRUE`, but when running it on the entire data frame, it results as `FALSE`. I think the issue could therefore be with how the data frame itself and not the variables.

Running `str(Environmental)` for example results in: `tibble [60 × 8] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)`, where 60 are my observations and 8 are my variables. Could this be what's causing the issue? [when running str(Environmental)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghs3m.png)

Thanks in advance and hope this was clear enough!